# Can WPF CollectionViews be created to bring together multiple columns of data

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have about a dozen ObservableCollections that hold objects which have dates, singles and integers.  All collections are of the same length and have data added and removed at the same time.  One of the ObservableCollections is the main one and is needed when referring to the others.

Is there a way to use CollectionViews to bring 2 of these ObservableCollections together in such a way that they look like one ObservableCollection having the total of all of the original columns when data bound to a datagrid and/or chart?  If so does anyone have an example?

Everything I have found shows the data from both sources being brought together by adding one on top of the other in what I would call a stack of data .

Thanks

Comment: All the same length and have data added and removed at the same time.  Sounds like one row about a single thing?  Then why not have a class that is all.  Then use views to break it down into the 12.

Comment: You could wrap all of the observable collections into one class (making it its own type) and then create a collectionView based on that class's type

Comment: Additional details:  At this point I have 1 base collection with an object that has 24 properties and 11 additional collections each with an object that has 19 properties.  As the app is used the 11 can easily go a 100 or more.  I have one class that calculates and populates the additional 11 ObservableCollections from data in the first.  An initial class with all properties would have 233 properties with no way to expand at runtime.  This would also make the controlling the charting and grids a nightmare.  I really need a way to bring the classes together as needed for data binding.

Comment: For the additional collections (11 - 100) are they all of the same type (class)?

Comment: Yes at this point they are. Also I do not know how many more there might be at runtime.

Comment: How can you have unknown classes at runtime?  Are you building up  dynamic classes?

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty but I have a similar application.
Have a class with 5 base properties then a variable number of fields.
The fields I put in a List.

Can bind rows to a collection but not columns.

So I use a ListView Gridview where I build up the columns in code behind.
Bind the columns to Field[0], Field[1], ...

In you case you could have base class Bclass with the base Properties and a Property  List

```
In your List<Fields> you just iterate the properties of the List<ExtensionClass>  

Clearly the List<Bclass> needs to all have List<Extension> class with the same length in every item of the binding breaks.
```

Comment: I have been looking at something similar; I am hoping someone has a more elegant and less maintenance solution.